# HTML5/js sqlite database not entering transaction function

Tags: javascript, sqlite, html

I have the following javascript function:

```
function initDatabase() {

    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases not supported in this browser');
    } else {
        var shortName = 'TestDB';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'HTML5 Test Database';
        var maxSize = 1024 * 1024;
        db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
        alert('opened db ' + db); //this says its a database

        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            alert('before create'); //never gets here
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person(FirstName TEXT, MiddleName TEXT, LastName TEXT);');
            alert('after create');
        });

        alert('after transaction'); //does get here
    }
}
```

being called on document ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        initDatabase();
    });
```

As you can see from the comments, the database appears to be created/opened (not sure how I can verify this though) but when I attempt create a transaction and execute some sql, the function never seems to be entered.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I verify that the database even exists?

I am using Chrome 14 for testing.

Thanks

Comment: A possibility would be to write `var db = openDatabase(...`  instead of `db = openDatabase(...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert seems to be the caveat. It might be suspending things causing it not to work.

`alert` is "superseded" by `console.log` anyway (in terms of debugging), and if I replace the alerts with logs, everything seems to work (I get all four logs).

(To view these `console.log` calls, you can press F12 and click on Console.)

Comment: Well that just makes me feel foolish. Thanks for the information. Everything seems to be working just fine without the alerts.